# How to use class with inheritance and polymorphism to find duplicated data

Tags: python, pandas, class

I have an assignment related to this kind of question. I'm suppose to find out the duplicated data from the data given with condition of different 'DB' but same 'TITLE', 'ISSN' and 'e-ISSN' using classes with inheritance and polymorphism.

Let's say these are the given data:

```
DB     TITLE                        ISSN            e-ISSN
M   Communications of the ACM   0001-0782         1557-7317
L   Communications of the ACM   0001-0782
J   Communications of the ACM   0001-0782
A   Advances in Human...        16875893
```

The output are more or less like this where the duplicated data will be written on the same row with the original data.

```
TITLE           DB  ISSN    e-ISSN          TITLE           DB  ISSN    e-ISSN  
Neuropathology  K   0919-6544               Neuropathology  P   0919-6544
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using comparison on 'TITLE' and produce a new dataframe. The new dataframe is compared on  'ISSN' and forth, But this method I don't think is applicable on class's polymorphism and inheritance.